# Discrete Mathematics Counting and Combinations/Variations Climbing Stairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Let's say we have a staircase that has $10$ steps. As we walk up the staircase we must always end on step $10$.

1. How many paths can I take up the staircase? Each path is distinguished by which steps I touch. For example, one path is Start $\rightarrow S_1 \rightarrow S_5 \rightarrow S_6 \rightarrow S_9 \rightarrow S_{10}$. I’m allowed to step
   over as many steps as I wish with each step - as long as I end on step $10$. Each step goes UP the staircase, never down.
2. How many ways can I take up the staircase if I step on exactly $4$ steps (including step $10$). With each step, I must advance at least one step forward - I can not take a step and remain on the same step.
3. How many paths up the stairs are there if with each step I’m allowed to skip at most one level. For example: Start $\rightarrow S_1 \rightarrow S_3 \rightarrow S_4 \rightarrow S_5 \rightarrow S_7 \rightarrow  S_9 \rightarrow S_{10}$ is one such path.

I have a general idea of how to setup the stairs problems for these if you are allowed to do a combination of going up and down the stairs but am unsure how to approach each of these problems for when you hae to go UP the staircase, never down.

Comment: Hint:  Note that a path is the same as a subset of $\{1,\cdots, 10\}$ which contains $1$ and $10$.

Comment: In the first problem, each path is determined by which subset of the first nine steps you touch.

Comment: For the solution to part 3, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599865/climbing-stairs-why-is-the-number-of-ways-i-can-reach-a-particular-step-the-su ; it's a Fibonacci sequence.