# Climbing Stairs - Why is the number of ways I can reach a particular step the sum of the previous and second prevoius steps?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, induction, intuition

There is a famous coding question which goes like :

`Given the number of steps, count ways I can reach the top step. At each step I can move either 1 step or 2 steps at a time.`

https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/description/

For example:
`Steps: 3 No. of ways 3`

Explanation:

1. `1 + 1 + 1`
2. `1 + 2`
3. `2 + 1`

Now it seems just by looking at the values over a couple of examples, you can find that the Fibonacci sequence gives the exact answer.

But my question is that why $$number\ of\ ways\ of\ step_i = number\ of\ ways\ of\ step_{i-1} + number\ of\ ways\ of\ step_{i-2}$$

**What is the intuition ?**

**All that I can figure out is that, lets say to go `step 3` you need to either on `step 1` (where you can make a 2-step jump) or on `step 2` (where you can make a 1-step time).**

But that's still confusing since from `step 1` you can make 1 step jumps to get to `step 3`. How is that not over-counted ?

Any help with the intuition ?

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you want to reach level $100$. Then, there is two cases to consider: Case1: We start with $1$ step and somehow climb the remaining $99$ steps. Case 2: We start with $2$ steps and somehow climb the remaining $98$ steps. Since the first moves are different, clearly, these two cases are disjoint. Also, they cover all possibilities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the ways to reach step $n$ as the sequences of steps chosen - so for example, as you've noted, the ways to reach the third step can be written as $(1, 1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2)$.

When looking at the ways to reach step $n$, we can separate the sequences by the last element. Meaning that we wind up with two lists:

1. All the sequences ending in $1$; and
2. All the sequences ending in $2$.

How many sequences end in $1$? Well, all of those sequences involve reaching step $n - 1$, then taking a single step (which adds the $1$ on the end). So the number of those sequences is the same as the number of ways we can reach step $n - 1$.

The same goes for sequences ending in $2$ - each one of them can be formed by taking one of the sequences that gets us to step $n - 2$ and adding a $2$ on the end.

So the total number of ways to reach step $n$ is equal to the sum of ways to reach steps $n - 1$ and $n - 2$.

Why is there no double counting? Notice that the two sets we formed are disjoint, meaning that a sequence can belong to one, or the other, but not both. If a sequence ends in $1$ then it belongs to the first set and it represents reaching step $n - 1$ and taking a single step; if it ends in $2$ then it belongs to the second step and represent reaching step $n - 2$ and taking two steps. Even if some of the sequences in step $1$ *also* visited step $n - 2$, they are clearly different sequences because one of them ends $(\ldots, 1, 1)$ and the other one ends $(\ldots, 2)$.